# Mysql counter field. counter++

Tags: mysql, database

How to save counters in mysql database correctly when querying at the same time? 
The counter at the same time saving to change to 1 and requests were 1000.

Comment: Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code so far?

Comment: You can't, a SELECT cannot insert/update db. You need to add more detail to the question.

Comment: code here not need requests 1,000 which'm changing counter, so as one simultaneous all will request significance 0 the retain 1, and in deeds 1,000